# MIT Android APP Inventor and Android application

Tags: android, json, excel

I make Android application into MIT APP Inventor, and on page I have 3 TextBox components. Application needs to read two values from JSON and into third TextBox needs write value from JSON.
JSON has this structure with Year(2023) and Month(1-12):

{
"2023": {
"1": 50.430618018683106,
"2": 51.181363951612525,
"3": 51.93210988454197,
"4": 52.68285581747139,
"5": 53.43360175040084,
"6": 54.18434768333026,
"7": 54.93509361625971,
"8": 55.685839549189126,
"9": 56.43658548211857,
"10": 57.18733141504799,
"11": 57.93807734797744,
"12": 58.68882328090686
},

I used DataFile component that I import JSON file, but I don't read third value from jSON.
Application display after my code started twoo large values.
[First procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OfMs.jpg)

I want to view only ona real values into third TextBox.

[Second part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDis2.jpg)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: How to view my code? JSON is viewed in question, I have three values for display and it is Year, Month and value of precipitation as real number.